# I need an SSRS Report with a header on every page, but a logo only on the first page

Tags: sql, reporting-services

The title says most of it, but to elaborate...

I have a simple table report with some grouping where the report can go onto many pages. I have been asked to modify the report so that the header text is shown on every page, but the logo in the header is only shown on the first page (to save ink).

I can get this to work with the logo below the text, as I just have it in the body rather than in the header...but I need to be able to put it above the text in the header.

I have been playing with the idea of placing the header text and logo in the table and trying to change the repeat, group, etc; but have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

This is for sql-2008 onwards.

Thanks in advance for any help.

edit:
I have tried to put the text in the header and set the header 'show on first page' to false and then put a duplicate of the header text with the logo above the table in the body...unfortunately, it preserves the space for the header on the first page even though it's not showing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the visibility of the image to be dependent on the page number.

```
  =IIF(Globals!OverallPageNumber = 1,false, true)
```

This will only display the image on page 1, but no other page.

Comment: ooh, so close...thank you for the answer. Do you know how I can get the header to reduce in size when the logo isn't there though?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, the header is the size it is to accommodate the layout. Could you possibly put the logo UNDER the text - put the logo on the report body and keep the text in the header?

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I asked if having the logo under the text would be okay, but have been told that it needs to go above it. I'm going to mark your response as the answer, as I think that it's as close as I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I feel I ought to add that it MAY be possible, just not as far as I know.

Comment: I have had some luck with "CanGrow" textboxes sitting in a narrow layout space, that enlarge the space they are in when they are given contents that require it.  I don't know if you can do this with an image, though.  Maybe if there is a narrow placeholder image that gets replaced with dynamic content that is loaded through a dataset?